# Why can't I compute $(-2)^\frac28$ using a calculator?

Tags: radicals, calculator

Why can't I compute $(-2)^\frac28$ using a calculator?

[image: 1]

Comment: What do you think the result should be?

Comment: Because with negative base the fraction powers *must* be reduced to lowest terms other wise they are ambiguous.   And when you reduce to lowest terms, negative numbers do not have even powered roots (for obvious reasons).

Comment: By the same flawed logic $\log(4)=\log((-2)^2)=2\log(-2)$

Comment: This number is not well-defined unless we use a definition based on complex numbers and fix the branch we use.

Answer (score 1):

In Real Analysis, $$\left[(-2)^2\right]^{(1/8)} \tag1 $$

is not equal to (for example)

$$\left[(-2)\right]^{(1/4)} \tag2 $$

or

$$\left[(-2)^{(1/8)}\right]^2. \tag3 $$

In Real Analysis, despite the fact that the expression in (1) above is well defined, the expressions in both (2) above and (3) above are undefined.

Similarly, $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined in Real Analysis.